# Python Password Generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, passwords

I am trying to create a password generator in Python that must contain an uppercase letter, lowercase letter, and a number, and must have a length between 6 and 20 characters.

```
   import random
   import string
   def password_gen():
        while True:
            length = random.randint(6,20)
            pwd = []
            for i in range(length):
                prob = random.random()
                if prob < 0.34:
                    char = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
                    pwd.append(char)
                elif prob < 0.67:
                    char = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
                    pwd.append(char)
                else:
                    char = str(random.randint(0,9))
                    pwd.append(char)
            pwd = ''.join(pwd)
            #check password here
            return pwd
```

However, I am having trouble checking the password to make sure it contains the required characters listed earlier. I am not sure if/how i would use a continue statement.Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be a bit easier to ensure you meet the base requirements if you just handle those upfront.

```
import random
import string

def generate_pw():
    length = random.randint(6,20) - 3
    pwd = []
    pwd.append(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase))
    pwd.append(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
    pwd.append(str(random.randint(0,9)))
    # fill out the rest of the characters
    # using whatever algorithm you want
    # for the next "length" characters
    random.shuffle(pwd)
    return ''.join(pwd)
```

This will ensure your password has the characters you need. For the rest of the characters you could for example just use a list of all alphanumeric characters and call `random.choice` `length` times.

Comment: Thank you! That seems like a simpler way to answering the question

Answer (score 1):

you can use isupper() and islower() functions to get does your password contain uppercase and lowercase.

e.g.

```
upper=0
lower=0
for i in range(length):
    if (pwd[i].islower()):
        upper=1
    elif (pwd[i].isupper()):
        lower=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string


def password_gen():
    lower_case_letter = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    upper_case_letter = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    number = random.choice(string.digits)
    other_characters = [
        random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
        for index in range(random.randint(3, 17))
    ]

    all_together = [lower_case_letter, upper_case_letter] + other_characters

    random.shuffle(all_together)

    return ''.join(all_together)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Password Generator more broken down, you can get any number you wish, but it outputs a pattern by first adding letters, then numbers and finally symbols

```
import random 
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))



passwordlength = nr_letters + nr_numbers + nr_symbols


chars = ""
for x in range (0, nr_letters): 
  char = random.choice(letters) 
  chars += char

nums = ""
for y in range (0, nr_numbers):
  num = random.choice(numbers)
  nums+=num

syms = "" # string accumulator 
for z in range (0, nr_symbols): 
  symb = random.choice(symbols)
  syms += symb

print(f"Here is your password: {chars}{nums}{syms}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete code that create a password generator in Python that contains an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, and a number, and have a length between 6 and 20 characters.

```
import random
import string

def generate_password():
while True:
    length = random.randint(6, 20)
    password = []
    password.append(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))  # Add an uppercase letter
    password.append(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase))  # Add a lowercase letter
    password.append(random.choice(string.digits))  # Add a number

    for _ in range(length - 3):
        password.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation))

    random.shuffle(password)
    generated_password = ''.join(password)

    if 6 <= len(generated_password) <= 20:
        return generated_password

generated_password = generate_password()
print("Generated Password:", generated_password)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).